# Configurable external Urls in HTML files based on different environment

Tags: javascript, html, sharepoint

My production sharepoint url is 
http://test.com/sites/prod

QA is 
http://test.com/sites/qa

and dev is 
http://test.com/sites/dev

and I have to change relative reference urls JS & CSS files(/sites/**dev**/) for each environment,is there any way to make it configurable?

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/sites/dev/Style%20Library/cocmt/css/kendo.common.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/sites/dev/Style%20Library/cocmt/css/kendo.default.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/sites/dev/Style%20Library/cocmt/css/kendo.default.mobile.min.css" />
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of url tokens.

You can use `~sitecollection` token which represents the URL of current site collection. If you want to get token of current site, you can use `~site` token.

So, you can modify your link as below:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="~sitecollection/Style%20Library/cocmt/css/kendo.common.min.css" />
```

Reference - [URL and tokens in SharePoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/general-development/urls-and-tokens-in-sharepoint)